# How To Make Class Default Returning Value A Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I hope the title is clear enough for my purpose, to be honest I did not try much because I didn't really knew where to go to, and I'm not even sure this is totally possible. I know its possible to override `__str__` and `__int__` to return values of those 2 types. I sure you're asking 'why not have a class function to return what you want', and sure its a reasonable question, but I wanted a cleaner way to do it.

I've searched for other similar questions and examples that might have helped but none really do what I intend. The closest I could get is from the example I tried below overriding `__new__` and `__repr__`.

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.info = {'name': name, 'age': age}
    def __new__(self, name, age):
        return self.info
    def __repr__(self, name, age):
        return self.info
student_data = student('Rob', 18)

print(student_data)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am sorry , English is not my native language and I was a bit confuse on how to make the actual question . But following the example i intend to have `self.info` as the "class returning value", so like when I simply do `print(student_data)` it should print the dictionary instead of the class instance. I hope I was clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Both `__str__` and `__repr__` must return a string. `print` will internally call your object's `__str__` representation. So, just have your `__str__` method return the string representation of `self.info` (IOW `str(self.info)`).

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.info = {'name': name, 'age': age}

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.info)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()
```

```
student_data = Student('Rob', 18)
print(student_data)
# {'name': 'Rob', 'age': 18}
```

Comment: Well that does it, thank you. However is there a way to return the dict as the object or must always return as string?

Comment: @PauloCosta The spec dictates that it return a string. Otherwise, just implement a getter method and call `student_data.get_info()`

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make an object act like a dictionary, you can subclass `dict` itself, or perhaps even easier, subclass [`collections.UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict).

```
import collections

class Student(collections.UserDict):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.data = {'name': name, 'age': age}

student_data = Student('Rob', 18)

print(student_data)
```